# Collation for URL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, collation

Warning: I know very little about database collations so apologies in advance if any of this is obvious...

We've got a database column that contains urls. We'd like to place a unique constraint/index on this column.

It's come to my attention that under the default db collation `Latin1_General_CI_AS`, dupes exist in this column because (for instance) the url `http://1.2.3.4:5678/someResource` and `http://1.2.3.4:5678/SomeResource` are considered equal. Frequently this is not the case... the kind of server this url points at **is** case sensitive.

What would be the most appropriate collation for such a column? Obviously case-sensitivity is a must, but `Latin1_General`? Are urls `Latin1_General`? I'm not bothered about a lexicographical ordering, but equality for unique indexes/grouping is important.

Comment: Why do you think that a collation is better than others? Is not enough to use CS ( ['CS specifies case-sensitive.'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180175.aspx) )?

Comment: Are you canonicalizing the URLs before insertion, e.g. preventing `http://host1/SomeResource` and `http://host1:80/SomeResource` from being added? If not, you're not going to gain much by adding this constraint.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, yes indeed. The URLs have been fully processed before insertion.

Comment: @danihp: My understanding is that under certain collations, pairs of characters are considered equal, yet under others they are not. If I'm correct, this would have a bearing on my choice of collation.

Comment: I understand, I post an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [alter table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190920.aspx) to set *CS* (Case Sensitive) collation for this column:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable 
       ALTER COLUMN URLColumn varchar(max) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

Also you can specify collation in the SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable
          WHERE UrlColumn like '%AbC%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

Here is a [short article](http://www.abstraction.net/ViewArticle.aspx?articleID=72) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

The letters `CI` in the collation indicates case insensitivity.

For a URL, which is going to be a small subset of latin characters and symbols, then try `Latin1_General_CS_AI`

Answer (score 1):

Latin1_General uses code page 1252 ([1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)) and URL's allowed characters are included on that code page([2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator#List_of_allowed_URL_characters)), so you can say that URLs are Latin1_General.

You just have to select the case sensitive option `Latin1_General_CS_AS`

Answer (score 1):

[rfc3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) says:

> The ABNF notation defines its terminal values to be non-negative
> integers (codepoints) based on the US-ASCII coded character set
> [ASCII].

Wikipedia say that allowed chars are:

```
Unreserved
May be encoded but it is not necessary
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 - _ . ~

Reserved
Have to be encoded sometimes
! * ' ( ) ; : @ & = + $ , / ? % # [ ]
```

It seems that they are not conflicts between this chars in compare operations. Also, you can use [HASHBYTES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx) function for make this comparation.

But this kind of operation is not the major problem. Major problem is that `http://domain:80`  and  `http://domain` may be the same. Also with encoded characters, a url may seems different with encoded chars.

In my opinion, RDBMS will incorporate this kind of structures as new data types: url, phone number, email address, mac address, password, latitude, longitude, ... . I think that collation can helps but don't will solve this issue.

Comment: Indeed... given that Uris are identifiers, I think their place as a top level datatype is well deserved.